# Questions Regarding DLL Loading in a Process Address Space

Tags: windows, dll, portable-executable

Well, I read several of Matt Pietrek's articles on Portable Executable (PE) files, like:

- An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format, [Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) and [Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx)
- [MSJ article on linkers](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0797/hood0797.aspx)
- [MSJ article on COFF format](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0498/hood0498.aspx)

In addition, I have read a few other sources on the subject. It is either me overlooking some parts, or the questions aren't answered there.

So, here are the questions:

It is known that, when loading an EXE, the Windows Loader reads the list of imported DLL's from the Importa Address Table (IAT), and loads them into the process address space.

1. The process address space is a virtual space. The DLL may have already loaded into some physical space. This happens for DLLs like `KERNEL32.dll` or `USER32.dll`. What is the relation between the physical and virtual address? Does the loader just allocate pages and copy the DLL, or does it make references?
2. If a DLL is not loaded, does the Loader load the whole DLL, or just the functions needed? For instance, if you used function `foo()` from `bar.dll`, does the loader load the whole `bar.dll` into the process address space? Or, does it just load the `foo`'s code into the process address space?
3. Assume your EXE file uses function `MessageBox()` from `USER32.DLL`, which resides in `%WINDIR%\system32\user32.dll`. Can you develop a customized `USER32.DLL`, put it in the same directory as your EXE file, and expect that your customized `MessageBox` is called by your app instead of the system'd default `MessageBox`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Re 1: physical addresses play no role, everything involved here is virtual memory.  The physical address is only established when a virtual memory page gets mapped into RAM, triggered by a page fault.  Many basic DLLs appear at the same virtual memory address in several processes, like kernel32.dll.  The processes simply share the same pages of code (not data).

Re 2: no actual 'loading' takes place, the feature used is the same one that supports memory mapped files.  The backing of these pages is the DLL file itself, not the paging file.  Nothing gets loaded until a page fault forces Windows to read the page from the file into RAM.  But yes, the entire code section of the DLL gets mapped.

Re 3: yes, that would work.  But it is next to impossible to make it work in practice since you will have to write replacement functions for *all* the user32 exports that your program uses.  Including the ones that other Win32 functions use, you cannot know.  API hooking is the typical technique used, Detours from Microsoft Labs is a good one.

Windows Internals edition 5 is an excellent book to learn more about the plumbing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. "...it is next to impossible to make...": Actually, I want to replace `WS2_32.DLL`. The EXE file uses only 5 functions from `WS2_32.DLL`, so it is plausible to replace that. In fact, I just want to prevent the EXE to connect to the internet, so I want to replace the TCP/IP `connect` function so that it does nothing. Is this sound?

Comment: It is not, lots of Windows DLLs use it.  And DLLs you don't know about, the ones that get loaded into your process when you use shell dialogs like GetOpenFileName().  Use Detours, as I recommended.

Answer (score 2):

1) When you create new process NT kernel loader allocates space for the process and map all PE sections on specified place. Then NT loader looks through import table, loads DLLs in process memory and correct pointers if necessary (it's called relocation).

2) Loader loads the whole DLL in process address space.

3) Yes, it will use `user32.dll` from the same directory where EXE is located. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). But as the most WinAPI functions located in `user32.dll` your custom dll must export a lot of them.

Comment: Correction on #2: The entire DLL is mapped into process address space, but only the pages that are actually used will be loaded into RAM (done by the virtual memory manager when a page-fault occurs).  On Windows, pages are most often 4kB each.

Comment: At least somebody said something about relocations :).  BTW, when a relocation occur's, those pages are marked private/non-sharable.  So relocation is very expensive from memory and time (modifying code for new address).